# How to debug Server Error 500 on Openshift, when rhc tail does not show errors?

Tags: openshift, python-3.3, django-1.7, openshift-client-tools

I'm trying to debug a Server Error 500 with my application. I've read that you should use `rhc tail` to show a live log stream and with the current error, the log stream that appears when trying to display the page is:

> ==> app-root/logs/python.log <==
>
> 79.24.253.62 - - [01/Jan/2015:08:32:17 -0500] "GET /url/ HTTP/1.1" 500 27 "http://a-b.rhcloud.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36"

The error shown is:

[image: picture showing "Server Error (500)"]

Other pages work, this error only appears on certain "more advanced" pages (eg. static pages show correctly). The rest of the log, is:

> ==> app-root/logs/python.log <==
>
> [Thu Jan 01 08:30:43 2015] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context unconfined_u:system_r:openshift_t:s0:c6,c654
>
> [Thu Jan 01 08:30:43 2015] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
>
> [Thu Jan 01 08:30:43 2015] [notice] Digest: done
>
> [Thu Jan 01 08:30:43 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/3.3.2 configured -- resuming normal operations

and:

> ==> app-root/logs/postgresql.log <==
>
> 2015-01-01 13:30:25 GMT LOG:  shutting down
>
> 2015-01-01 13:30:25 GMT LOG:  database system is shut down
>
> 2015-01-01 13:30:31 GMT LOG:  could not bind socket for statistics collector: Permission denied
>
> 2015-01-01 13:30:31 GMT LOG:  trying another address for the statistics collector
>
> 2015-01-01 13:30:31 GMT LOG:  could not bind socket for statistics collector: Cannot assign requested address
>
> 2015-01-01 13:30:31 GMT LOG:  disabling statistics collector for lack of working socket
>
> 2015-01-01 13:30:31 GMT WARNING:  autovacuum not started because of misconfiguration
>
> 2015-01-01 13:30:31 GMT HINT:  Enable the "track_counts" option.
>
> 2015-01-01 13:30:31 GMT LOG:  database system was shut down at 2015-01-01 13:30:25 GMT
>
> 2015-01-01 13:30:31 GMT LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections

What is the next step to debug this problem?

Comment: It looks like the error has something to do with how you configured your data base.

Comment: @fatfantasma There's no custom configuration.

Comment: Does your _application_ have a log?

Comment: @ptrk You mean log at the application level (custom log)? If so no, the python and database log is shown in the question body. I've tested it locally and it was about `urllib.quote` not existing in Python 3, so I have fixed that. But the problem of "how to debug this kind of errors" remains. :)

Comment: Have you set `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in `settings.py`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the following Django logging configuration which gave me the details of the 500 errors in a file django.log. I set `LOG_DIR = os.environ.get('OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR')`

```
LOGGING = {
  'version': 1,
  'disable_existing_loggers': False,
  'handlers': {
    'file': {
      'level': 'WARNING',
      'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
      'filename': os.path.join(LOG_DIR, 'django.log'),
    },
  },
  'loggers': {
    'django.request': {
      'handlers': ['file'],
      'level': 'WARNING',
      'propagate': True,
    },
  },
}
```